# Windows Server 2003 FTP Last Modified Date

Tags: windows-server-2003, ftp

I'm working on a client for a Windows Server 2003 Ftp. When looking at the Last Modified Date I see the time is "rounded" to minutes (seconds are always zero), can anyone confirm this behavior ?

Answer (score 2):

No, no, that's not how it works at all.

The `Last Modified Date` is a file system attribute and is not rounded off to the minute.

I suppose it's possible that you have some FTP client that rounds that attribute off to the minute *in its display*, or doesn't know how to display the seconds properly (and displays them as zeros instead), but the `Last Modified Date` attribute is most certainly not being rounded off to the minute by anything.